# Remove and Add letters in Strings

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to solve a problem in C#.

Here is the task:

> - If a word *begins* with a *vowel* (a, e, i, o, u or A, E, I, O, U), *remove*
>     the first letter and append it to the end, then add **"che"**. If you have
>     the word “orange” It translates to “rangeoche”
> - If a word *begins* with a *consonant* (i.e. not a vowel), append **"che"** to the end of the word. For example, the word "chicken" becomes
>     "chickenche".
> - If the word has *even number* of letters append one more **"e"** to the end of it.
>
> Print the translated sentence.

**Example:**

```
Hello there Amy
```

**Output:**

```
Helloche thereche myAche
```

Here is what I have done so far :

```
        string Sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] output = Sentence.Split(' ');
        char letter;
        string che = "che";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Sentence);
        foreach (string s in output)
        {
            letter = s[0];

            if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'E' || letter == 'i'
            || letter == 'I' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'O' || letter == 'u' || letter == 'U')
            {
             //  Console.WriteLine("first char of the word is a vowel");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Insert(s.Length,che);
              //  Console.WriteLine("first char of a word is a consonant");
            }

            if (s.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
              //  Console.WriteLine("the word has even numbers of letters");
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(firstchar);
            int currentWordLength = s.Length;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

The problem is I cannot add `"che"` or remove vowels of words because the *index is moving* due to those changes. I can only change the first word. My ifs are correct because if I uncomment the `Console.Writelines` they scan through each word.
I am just struggling with the adding/removing of each word. Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: No need to mess around with StringBuilder, it is just a distraction. (unless you specifically are instructed to use it). Think of it as follows: If a string starts with a vowel, take the remainder of the string (behind the vowel) and add the vowel to it. Adding strings together to form a new string is simple, just use `+`. :-) Note that this does not require moving the vowel around in the original source string, just make a new string with the parts i mentioned...

Comment: Note that you add "che" in all cases - so make that a common case.  How do you handle y?

Comment: @elgonzo . Thank you very much for it  worked!!. I have followed your advice. 
Under vowels I have created
string newword = s.Substring(1) + s[0] + "che";
Under consonants :
string newword = s + "che";
In each case I have checked if the length of the word is even or odd and I have added if case to each condition. 
For example in the vowels case if the length % 2 = 0 I used Console.Write(newword + "e" + " ");
else 
Console.Write(newword + " ");
 In the consosant case I followed the same logic. 
I had no understanding of Regex and methods yet and I was just starting with StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create `StringBuilder` object and append appropriate `string` into the `IF` condition. Try with the below code:

```
    string Sentence = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] output = Sentence.Split(' ');
    char letter;
    string che = "che";
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    string strFinal = "";
    foreach (string s in output)
    {
        letter = s[0];
        sb = new StringBuilder(s);

        if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'E' || letter == 'i'
        || letter == 'I' || letter == 'o' || letter == 'O' || letter == 'u' || letter == 'U')
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("first char of the word is a vowel");
            string s1 = sb.Remove(0, 1).ToString();
            sb.Insert(s1.Length, letter);
            sb.Insert(sb.Length, che);
        }
        else
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("first char of a word is a consonant");
            sb.Insert(s.Length, che);
        }

        if (s.Length % 2 == 0)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("the word has even numbers of letters");
            // sb.Insert(s.Length, "e");
            sb.Insert(sb.Length, "e");
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(firstchar);
        int currentWordLength = s.Length;

        strFinal += sb + " ";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(strFinal);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I like that. I will try it, as I was just learning StringBuilder.

Comment: @grozdeto I ran and tested at my end. Definitely it will work fine. The output matches your demand. If you get help from this answer, don't forget to accept it please. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your help but it does not work for all the examples. 

For input: 
He is no spring chicken anymore
The output is:

Heeche sieche noeche springeche chickenche nymoreache

The correct output should be:
Hechee sichee nochee springchee chickenche nymoreache

Comment: @grozdeto Hey bro, there is a silly mistake inside the `IF` (related to even calc) condition. It would be  `sb.Length` instead of `s.Length`. I have corrected the answer. Please check once again.

Comment: @grozdeto Corrected line should be `sb.Insert(sb.Length, "e");`

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend changing your translation code to have a function that acts on words, instead of the whole sentence. So the code in `foreach (string s in output)` should be moved to another function that just acts on that string.  And don't try to manipulate the string passed it, create a new one based on the logic you've listed. Once you've created the translated string, return it to the caller.  The caller would then reconstruct the sentence from each returned translation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from splitting the initial problem into smaller ones, with a help of *extract methods*:

```
  using using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  private static String ConvertWord(string word) {
    //TODO: Solution here 
    return word; // <- Stub
  }

  private static String ConvertPhrase(string phrase) {
    // Regex (not Split) to preserve punctuation: 
    // we convert each word (continued sequence of letter A..Z a..z or ')
    // within the original phrase 
    return Regex.Replace(phrase, @"[A-Za-z']+", match => ConvertWord(match.Value));

    // Or if there's guarantee, that space is the only separator:
    // return string.Join(" ", phrase
    //   .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
    //   .Select(item => ConvertWord(item)));
  }
```

Now it's time to implement `ConvertWord`:

```
  private static String ConvertWord(string word) {
    // Do not forget of special cases - e.g. empty string
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word)) 
      return "chee";

    //  If the word has even number of letters append one more "e" to the end of it. 
    string suffix = word.Length % 2 == 0 ? "chee" : "che"; 

    // To cases: starting from vowel / consonant
    char letter = char.ToUpper(word[0]); 

    if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'E' || letter == 'I' || letter == 'O' || letter == 'U')
      return word.Substring(1) + word.Substring(0, 1) + suffix;
    else
      return word + suffix;
  }
```

Finally

```
  string Sentence = Console.ReadLine();

  Console.Write(ConvertPhrase(Sentence));
```

For test input

```
"It's just a simple test (demo only): nothing more!"
```

Will get

```
t'sIchee justchee ache simplechee testchee (demochee nlyochee): nothingche morechee!
```

Comment: Regex when it’s obviously a beginner’s homework or learning excercise?

Comment: @InBetween: I'm sorry for `Regex` (which is quite simple) but it seems to be the easiest way to extract *word* in case punctuation is present in the sentence: `Split` will get `(demo` not `demo`. Some homeworks are in fact more difficult than they are supposed to be.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think *you* are making it harder than it needs to be. There is absolutely no requirement in OP about punctuation nor does it seem to be an expected or considered input given the level of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Using the obvious extension methods:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    // ***
    // *** int Extensions
    // ***
    public static bool IsEven(this int n) => n % 2 == 0;

    // ***
    // *** String Extensions
    // ***
    public static bool StartsWithOneOf(this string s, HashSet<char> starts) => starts.Contains(s[0]);
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings);
}
```

You can use LINQ to process the rules:

```
var vowels = "aeiouAEIOU".ToHashSet();

var ans = src.Split(' ')
             .Select(w => (w.StartsWithOneOf(vowels) ? w.Substring(1)+w[0] : w)+"che"+(w.Length.IsEven() ? "e" : ""))
             .Join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't change your word before the end of `if`s. you need to test all of the conditions and save the result in another values, finally do changes on the word:

```
foreach (string s in output)
    {
        letter = char.ToLower(s[0]);
        bool isVowel = false;
        bool isEven = false;

        if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i'
         || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u')
        {
           isVowel = true;
        }            

        if (s.Length % 2 == 0)
        {
            isEven = true;
        }

        //Now you can change the word
        if (isVowel)
        {
            //Do What you want
        }

        if (isEven)
        {
            //Do What you want
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(firstchar);
        int currentWordLength = s.Length;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say break the logic into specific units so you can write tests,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var inputs = input.Split(' ');
        var sentence = string.Join(" ", inputs.Select(ConvertWord));
        Console.Write(sentence);
        Console.Read();
    }

    internal static string ConvertWord(string input)
    {
        const string che = "che";

        var vowels = new List<string>
        {
            "a","A", "e", "E", "i", "I", "o", "O", "u", "U"
        };

        var firstChar = input.First();

        var startsWithVowel = vowels.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Equals(firstChar));

        string rule2String, output;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startsWithVowel))
        {
            output = input + che;
        }

        else
        {
            output = input.Substring(1) + startsWithVowel + che;
        }

        rule2String = IsLengthEven(input)
            ? output + "e"
            : output
        ;

        return rule2String;
    }

    internal static bool IsLengthEven(string input)
    {
        return input.Length % 2 == 0;
    }
```

Hope this Helps!
PS: I have not covered the edge cases

Comment: In your code, `startsWithVowel` will always be `null`. Also, why are you making the vowel test so needlessly over-complicated? Why would you not want to use a simple char array/list in conjunction with the `Contains` method...?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use String.Join using Linq with String.Format. Then the solution is quite easy:

```
    private String convertSentence() {
        var sentence = "Hello there Amy";
        var vowels = "aeiou";
        var che = "che";

        return String.Join(" ", (
                from s in sentence.Split(' ')
                let moveFirstToEnd = vowels.Contains(s.ToLower()[0]) && s.Length > 1 
                select String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}"
                    , moveFirstToEnd ? s.Substring(1) : s
                    , moveFirstToEnd ? s.Substring(0, 1) : String.Empty
                    , che
                    , s.Length % 2 == 0 ? "e" : String.Empty
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: It is rather clear from the question that it is some school homework/assignment or coursework to learn basics about programming. While i believe your answer works (in a technical sense), it completely misses the mark by using a comparatively complex Linq query that is lightyears beyond the scope of the homework assignment asked about.

Comment: Why to downvote a good answer? Even if it is homework, other people use Stackoverflow too to find answers. Not only the one who asked this question looks at this page.